# Accidentally deleted files using OS. How to restore them?

Tags: perforce

Sequence of events:

1. created a file A
2. added it to the repository : `p4 add A`
3. submitted it to the repository : `p4 submit A`
4. accidentally removed it from my working directory: `\rm -f A`

What is the magic p4 command which will bring it back to my working directory?

Tried and it did not work

```
 1. p4 sync
 2. p4 sync -f 
 3. p4 edit A
 4. p4 sync A
 5. p4 sync -f A
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file is open for edit (and if this is the case, shame on you for omitting it from your initial sequence of events), `sync -f` won't touch it until you revert, at which point you'll get back the depot version of the file.  Just do:

```
p4 revert A
```

If the file is not open, then `p4 sync -f A` should do it, but the command you really want is:

```
p4 clean
```

which will go through your entire client and "clean" any unopen files that don't match your synced state.  To see your synced state, use `p4 have` (with or without a file argument).

---

The sequence of events in this particular case went something like:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 edit foo
//stream/main/foo#4 - opened for edit

C:\Perforce\test>del foo
```

At this point, `foo` is open for edit, but is missing from the local filesystem.  Attempting to submit it will fail, because it's open for `edit`, not `delete`:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 submit -d "my awesome edit"
Submitting change 156.
Locking 1 files ...
edit //stream/main/foo#5
open for read: c:\Perforce\test\foo: The system cannot find the file specified.
Submit aborted -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 156'.
Some file(s) could not be transferred from client.
```

Doing a `p4 sync -f` won't do anything because `sync` always skips over opened files except to update the working revision; since you're already working at the head revision it will simply report "up to date":

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 sync -f foo
foo - file(s) up-to-date.
```

Likewise, `p4 edit` won't do anything, because (a) the file is already open for edit and (b) `p4 edit` only opens the existing file in your workspace; it does not sync it or in any way modify its contents.  (It does do a chmod, but if the chmod fails the file is open regardless.)

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 edit foo
//stream/main/foo#4 - currently opened for edit
(file is still missing)
```

One way to fix the missing file situation is to replace the original file manually, either by copying it from elsewhere or by using `p4 print` as below:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 print -o foo //stream/main/foo
//stream/main/foo#4 - edit change 119 (text)
```

The manual replacement method runs the risk that the content doesn't match the revision you checked out, though, which can lead to missing data (i.e. you'll fool the conflict resolution logic into thinking you've deliberately added/removed a change based on the version of the file you just grabbed).

Instead I'd recommend doing a revert and reopening the file:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 revert foo
//stream/main/foo#4 - was edit, unlocked and reverted

C:\Perforce\test>p4 edit foo
//stream/main/foo#4 - opened for edit
```

The `revert` will replace the file with the appropriate depot revision automatically; when you reopen it for edit you have a fresh start.

Comment: Nope. I did not omit any steps in my  initial sequence of events.   Nope the command `p4 sync -f A`  did not work. But I solved it by copied the file A from the coworker's work space `cp /from/co/worker/path/to/A .` then  `p4 edit A` worked.  Made appropriate changes to A. Saved the A and  then issued  `p4 submit A`.  This was not the elegant procedure but it worked.

Comment: A missing local file does not stop `p4 edit` from working.  Will update answer with the sequence of events that I'm now 100% certain happened.  :)